# Anyone outright understand on built kernel #number output info

Tags: linux, kernel

Help explain
What's linux kernel #n, with n as small number: 1,2,3.. so on, acquired from just compiled one in kernel package all about?

sort of:

```
$ make
...
...
...
...
arch/x86/boot/bzimage (#4)

$
```